# Как передать список из другого класса JAVA

Tags: java, классы, arraylist, переменные

Есть первый класс

```
public class Main {
private ArrayList<String> authuser = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayList<String> getAuthuser() {
return this.authuser;
}
}
```

Есть второй класс

```
public class Infol {
Main main;
ArrayList<String> authuser = main.getAuthuser(); // при добавление этой записи код не работает
}
```

Нужно из первого передать список во второй класс. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

```
   public class Infol {

   Main main;

   public ArrayList<String> getListFromMainField () {
       return this.main.getAuthuser();
   }

   }
```

Comment: Ошибок не выдает, но как этим пользоваться, допустим я хочу взять 1 элемент, к чему мне обращаться? Прости, что я такой тупой, я всего 3 дня java изучаю. По идее должно быть sting s = authuser[0](возможно .toString или .Text я хз потом проверю, но это не суть важно), я обращаюсь к переменной(списку) authuser. А тут как вообще хз, я попробовал `ArrayList<String> authuser = this.getListFromMainField();` - не прокатило.

Comment: Тогда вы слишком далеко забрались, для начального уровня. Начните с чего нибудь попроще.
Как этим пользоваться. Можно инициализировать лист любой, и присвоить ему значение объекта ArrayList<String> temp = [Object Infol name].getListFromMainField();

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.